# Result set different from query than from stored procedure in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a sp that is giving me wrong results. That sp returns a cursor which is missing some rows. Now

1. When we fire the query within the sp directly in a query window, correct results come up. The only difference in this query is that instead of a cursor, the query directly outputs the result set; i.e. no cursor is opened when we fire the query directly.
2. When we recompile the sp, correct results come up for some time, and then it is back to missing rows after some time.

Have not been able to make much progress on this. Any pointers on what to look for, how to make progress etc. are much appreciated. I can paste the sp in here if needed, and probably the sp can be rewritten in some other way to make the problem go away, but I am more interested in knowing root cause - what could be causing this strange problem?

SP

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP_GETTAXSETTINGCHANNELINFO" (v_bid                   varchar2,
                             p_rdTaxSetting          out SYS_REFCURSOR) as
vT_bid varchar2(100);

begin
   vT_bid := v_bid;

    Open p_rdTaxSetting for
    Select taxmappingid, CHANNELNAME,PROPERTYNAME, PROPERTYID, TAXTYPE, ISPARTIALLYINCLUSIVE, PARTIALLYINCLUSIVEVALUE
    FROM (
    WITH ChannelData AS (
    SELECT ONDEMAND_SELECTED_SOURCES AS OnDemandChannels,
    SCHEDULED_SELECTED_SOURCES AS ScheduledChannels
    FROM SUB_ORDER S
    INNER JOIN CONTACT C ON S.Supplier_ID = C.Contact_ID
    WHERE C.BID = vT_bid
    AND S.STATUS='Complete' and current_ind = 1
    ),
    Property_Data As (
    SELECT
    SC.PROPERTY_NUM AS PropertyID
    ,SC.Company_Name as PropertyName
    ,SC.competitor_number as PropertyOrder
    FROM SUB_ORDER S
    INNER JOIN CONTACT C ON S.Supplier_ID = C.Contact_ID
    INNER JOIN SUB_ORDER_COMPETITOR SC ON S.Order_Id = SC.Order_ID
    WHERE C.BID = vT_bid
    AND S.STATUS='Complete' and current_ind = 1
    ),
    ODChannel as (
           select regexp_substr (OnDemandChannels, '[^,]+', 1, rn)  as Channel
           from (Select OnDemandChannels From ChannelData)
           cross join
           (select rownum rn
           from (select max (length (regexp_replace (OnDemandChannels, '[^,]+'))) + 1 max_value
           from (Select OnDemandChannels From ChannelData))
           connect by level <= max_value)
           where regexp_substr (OnDemandChannels, '[^,]+', 1, rn) is not null
    ),
    SCDChannel As (
           select regexp_substr (ScheduledChannels, '[^,]+', 1, rn) as Channel
           from (Select ScheduledChannels From ChannelData)
           cross join
           (select rownum rn
           from (select max (length (regexp_replace (ScheduledChannels, '[^,]+'))) + 1 max_value
           from (Select ScheduledChannels From ChannelData))
           connect by level <= max_value)
           where regexp_substr (ScheduledChannels, '[^,]+', 1, rn) is not null
    ),
    ChaData1 As (
      Select
        CASE lower(Channel)
          WHEN 'galileo' then 'GDS'
          else Channel
          end AS Channel
      from ODChannel
    ),
   ChaData2 As (
      Select CASE lower(Channel)
          WHEN 'galileo' then 'GDS'
          else Channel
          end AS Channel  FROM SCDChannel
    ),
    PropData  As (
      Select Distinct PropertyID,PropertyName  from Property_Data
      order by PropertyID
    ),
    AllChannel AS (
      Select Channel From ChaData1
      union
      Select Channel From ChaData2
    ),
    Prop_Cha_Data As (
        Select Distinct Channel,PropertyID,PropertyName  from AllChannel,Property_Data
        order by Channel,PropertyID
      ),
   Tax_Channel_Prop_Exists AS ( select
      CASE lower(CHANNELNAME)
      WHEN 'galileo' then 'GDS'
      else CHANNELNAME
      end AS CHANNELNAME,
      PropertyName As PROPERTYNAME, TCP.PROPERTYID As PROPERTYID,TAXTYPE,
    ISPARTIALLYINCLUSIVE, PARTIALLYINCLUSIVEVALUE,taxmappingid
    from TAXSETTING_CHANNEL_PROPERTY TCP
    INNER JOIN AllChannel PC On TRIM (CASE lower(TCP.CHANNELNAME)
          WHEN 'galileo' then 'GDS'else TCP.CHANNELNAME end)  = TRIM(PC.Channel)
    INNER JOIN PropData CP On TCP.PROPERTYID = CP.PropertyID
    where TCP.BID=vT_bid
    )
    Select Distinct taxmappingid, CHANNELNAME,PROPERTYNAME, PROPERTYID, TAXTYPE, ISPARTIALLYINCLUSIVE, PARTIALLYINCLUSIVEVALUE from Tax_Channel_Prop_Exists
     UNION ALL
      select DISTINCT 0 As taxmappingid, PCD.Channel As CHANNELNAME,
      PCD.PropertyName  As PROPERTYNAME ,
      PCD.propertyid As PROPERTYID,
      -1 As TAXTYPE,
      0 As ISPARTIALLYINCLUSIVE,
        '' As PARTIALLYINCLUSIVEVALUE
        FROM Prop_Cha_Data PCD
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
         Select taxmappingid FROM Tax_Channel_Prop_Exists E
         WHERE  E.channelname = PCD.Channel AND
          E.propertyid = PCD.propertyid )
        )
        Order by PROPERTYNAME,CHANNELNAME ;


end SP_GetTaxSettingChannelInfo;
```

Comment: It sounds like the procedure code would be relevant here. Are you using synonyms some where ? is the procedure and the query your executing are invoked from the same db user? is the query using `sysdate` / `timestamps` that might alter the query result based on the time it was executed ? Are you using RLS/VPD policies ? btw, when executing sql "directly" a cursor is open and fetched explicitly.

Comment: The sp and query are fired from the same db user. even if the sp and query are using dates, I am firing them one after the other. They display different results right then and there. I do not understand RLS/VPD. The query is making use of WITH. The sp is longish ... I was hoping to get some leads without going into sp code.

Comment: query `ALL_POLICIES` to check if there are any VPD/RLS policies on the table. run `explain plan` to check for odd predicates. oracle does not just give unstable results.

Comment: I understand Oracle does not give unstable results. I checked the policies; none are defined.

Comment: Posted the entire SP. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: This is one horrible piece of SQL. I hope it's not something you run frequently or on a regular basis .... This statement alone violates almost every best practice out there. none the less, I cant see any reason why it would produce different results when fetched from a procedure or sqlplus. is it possible you'r manipulating or displaying the results incorrectly from the ref cursor ?